# How do i get a specky looking metal through material nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, photorealism

This question might be rather specific, but i'm trying to replicate my laptop in a 3D render.
(specifically, xiaomi notebook pro)

I cant seem to get the specky metal of the laptop. This is my current node, i thought increasing specular would give a "specular" look but didnt seem like it:

[image]

and result, which looks rather flat without character:

[image]

However, i was looking at more towards this result:

(a close up shot of the real metal)

[image]

(from afar)

[image]

My question is, what material nodes should I add to recreate this material?

Comment: Noise texture plugged into Roughness or Normal socket ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a rough surface, you can use the Bump node.

1. Use a fine Noise Texture as a base (with UV or Object coords)
2. Add a *Bump node* and use *Distance value* to control the intensity
3. The *Distance value* is in meters. So I'd set it to around 0,0001.

[image]

[image]